# cruise control -how to execute batch file in cruise control and how to publish in different folder using cruise control

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, batch-file

1.I am getting below errror while executing batch file in cruise control:

```
<exception><![CDATA[ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Tasks.BuilderException: Command Line Build timed out (after 600 seconds)
```

code which i used is

```
 <exec>
    <executable>D:\DITBUILT.bat</executable>
 </exec>
```

2.I want to publish in different folder using cruise control..  I am using the code... I am not able to publish in different folder

```
<executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe</executable>
<workingDirectory>D:\Cas_CC\SourceCode\PolandSME-MAIN\SRC\UI</workingDirectory>
<projectFile>CAS.sln</projectFile>
<buildArgs> /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" </buildArgs>      
<targets>Build</targets>
<logger>ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.XmlLogger,D:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
```

Please help me out

1. how to publish in different folder using cruise control
2. how to execute a batch file using cruise control...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more precise. What kind of error are you getting? What do you mean by publish in this scenario - deploy on IIS?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting with the batch file might be resolved by using cmd.exe as executable and "/c D:\DITBUILT.bat" as arguments?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using cruise control with NANT.

```
<tasks>
      <nant>
        <executable>C:\Nant\Nant0.86\bin\nant.exe</executable>
        <baseDirectory>.</baseDirectory>
        <buildFile>C:\NANT_SCRIPTS\build.xml</buildFile>
        <targetList>
          <target>YourProject_Publish</target>
        </targetList>
        <buildTimeoutSeconds>2000</buildTimeoutSeconds>
      </nant>
    </tasks>
```

In your build.xml file you can use NANT commands to execute your bat files or pretty much do anything else. It supports the 3.5 framework as well.

```
 <exec program="C:\NANT_SCRIPTS\publish\YourProject.bat" />
    <delete dir="${web01}\yourSite.com\WebFolder" />
    <copy todir="${web01}\yourSite.com\WebFolder" >
      <fileset basedir="C:\CruiseControl\ProjectFolders\YourProject\Website" >
        <include name="*.aspx" />
        <include name="*.config" />
        <include name="*.master" />
        <include name="*.asax" />
        <include name="*.ascx" />
        <include name="*.sitemap" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
```